# Why is my file-like class only returning empty strings after the first call to readline?

Tags: python, file, io

I've created a small class to add a layer of encryption on top of python's `tempfile.TemporaryFIle`.  My first call to `readline` returns a line (as expected), but all subsequent calls to that function return empty strings.

Before showing you the source code, here is an example of said behavior:

```
lines = ["Now is the winter of our discontent",
        "Made glorious summer by this sun of York;",
        "And all the clouds that lour'd upon our house",
        "In the deep bosom of the ociean buried."]

f = EphemeralFile()
f.write('\n'.join(lines))  # just in case writelines is screwing up as well

f.readline()
f.readline()
```

**Output:**

```
'Now is the winter of our discontent'
''
```

And now here is the commented class method.  Note that the class to which this method belongs is **not** a subclass of `File`.  Instead, it holds a reference to a `tempfile.TemporaryFile` and aliases such methods as `self.tell` to the `TemporaryFile`'s tell method:

```
def readline(self, size=-1):
    fptr = self.tell()  # alias of self._file.tell
    bytes = []
    got_line = False
    while not got_line:
        # self.read is NOT an alias, but calls self._file.read
        bytes.append(self.read(256))  
        offset = '\n' in bytes[-1]
        if not bytes[-1] or offset:
            end = bytes.pop().split('\n', 1)[0]
            bytes.append(end)
            got_line = True

    plaintext = ''.join(bytes)
    # seek is aliased from self._file.seek
    self.seek(fptr + len(plaintext) + offset)  # rewind; offset is bool.
    return plaintext
```

I can't for the life of me figure out where I've gone wrong.  I have a nagging suspicion that this is a silly oversight on my part, so a fresh set of eyes would be most welcome.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** For those interested, [here](https://github.com/louist87/ephemeral/blob/master/ephemeral/__init__.py) is the whole class.

Comment: Did you seek back to the start before reading? If you write to a file, the file pointer moves along. Reading will start from that position, at the end of the file.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I did before calling `readline` initially (which is why the first line is returned).  After that, no, but that shouldn't matter since I'm seeking back before returning my line in the class method.  Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Have you considered making a generator to spit out each line individually?

Comment: @blz: without seeing the rest of the file class it's impossible to say if it is buffering writes somewhere.

Comment: Crowbeak:  "Frist make it work, then make it elegant, then make it fast".  I do plan on doing this, but only after I can get it to do *something* correctly =)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, good point.  [Here's the whole class](https://github.com/louist87/ephemeral/blob/master/ephemeral/__init__.py).  It's rather short as you can tell.

Comment: @blz: Hrm, I'd try to use `.flush()` then `.seek(0)` then read. There is no buffer for the writes in the class itself indeed.

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation: you are on Windows and have opened the file in text mode. Lines end in `\r\n` but the `\r` character is removed for you. Then when you think you seek to the next line you actually end up on the `\n`.

By the way, the return value of `readline()` should include the `\n` so callers can distinguish between empty lines and end of file.

Comment: Hmm good thought, but 1) I'm on linux 2) files are opened in binary mode by default.